# Python: global name is not defined OR object is referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to use numpy and pydicom to make a 3D stack of images for filtering with ITK. I'm having trouble getting the stacker function to return the stacked images, though.

If I remove the global variable declarations, I get an error saying I referenced imstack before I defined it. If I declare the variables as global, I get an error saying that the global name isn't defined. Sort of a Catch 22... Not exactly sure what I should do, and I know that globals are pretty evil so if I don't have to use them, I'd like not to.

```
def imgstacker(path):

    import os
    import dicom as dcm
    import numpy as np

    global imstack
    global slope
    global intercept

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        zlen = len(files)
        sizer = dcm.read_file(path+files[0],force=True)
        slope = sizer.RescaleSlope
        intercept = sizer.RescaleIntercept
        xlen = sizer.pixel_array.shape[0]
        ylen = sizer.pixel_array.shape[1]
        del sizer
        imstack = np.empty((zlen,xlen,ylen),dtype=np.int16)

        for i in range(0,zlen):
            print ('Reading: ' + path + files[i])
            img_raw = dcm.read_file(path + files[i],force=True)
            img = img_raw.pixel_array
            imstack[i,:,:] = img

    return imstack, slope, intercept
```

The code in my main script to run this module is:

```
imstack, slope, intercept = imgstacker('/my/favorite/directory')
```

The traceback if I remove the global definitions is:

```
 UnboundLocalError Traceback (most recent call last) 
 K:\dir\main.py in <module>() 6 import matplotlib.cm as cm 
 imstack, slope, intercept = imgstacker('my/favorite/directory\\')
 out = temp_test(imstack*slope + intercept) 
 K:\dir\imgstacker.py in imgstacker(path)
 intercept = img_raw.RescaleIntercept 
 return imstack, slope, intercept 
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'imstack' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Instead of `global imstack` try `imstack = None`

Comment: @Tim Casteljins TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I'm iterating over imstack and adding a new 'layer' each time. I don't think this is suitable.

Comment: Try checking that the directory exists first. It's possible that `os.walk` iterates through no items, in which case none of your variables are defined when you reach `return`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if None is not iterable if it is replaced by an iterable before use.

Comment: @Kevin The directory certainly exists, I've gone into python and done the code by hand about as much. I'm just trying to 'automate' the process since adding images to a big stack iteratively by hand will give me carpal tunnel syndrome.

Comment: @RobertJacobs I tried again assigning imstack, slope, and intercept to None on separate lines. I get the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType.' My code actually proceeded through the function above as if imstack were NoneType and then tried to proceed into the next function, crashing

Comment: could the problem be that you are referencing the variable `imstack` in your main script before calling the function?

Comment: Where and how are imstack, slope and intercept defined? Can't they be defined inside of `imgstacker`? "global" refers to a module level variable, not really project level, there's not much danger in using it.

Comment: @DanielJimenez No, I import my necessary modules and immediately assign in to imgstacker's outputs... the error is in imgstacker.py not main.py

Comment: @janzegan I'm not sure what you mean. The point is that they're defined/modified inside imgstacker and spat back out into the main function so I can process the image block.

Comment: thge traceback indicates that your os.walk is not being entered into ... ergo the directory does not exist or perhaps it is simply empty ... I would also hazzard a guess that you are not seeing your debug "Reading: " message printed anywhere

Comment: @JoranBeasley On a Windows machine, I enter the path string like this, correct?: pathname = 'K:\my\favorite\directory\' Or do I do it like this?: pathname = 'K:\\my\\favorite\\directory\\'

Comment: just us `/` that works for all os's in python and doesnt need rawstrings or escapes but either `path=r"C:\test"` or `path = "C:\\test"` or `path="C:/test"` will all behave correctly, `path="C:\test"` will not

Comment: Aha! Well there we go. I'm the first to admit I'm an idiot. If you edit your answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for bearing with me. I'm trying to learn python, SITK, numpy, and general programming etiquette all at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need the globals at all ... but i dont think this error is your only problem ... I think you have fundamental logic problems with this script

```
def imgstacker(path):

    import os
    import dicom as dcm
    import numpy as np

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        zlen = len(files)
        sizer = dcm.read_file(path+files[0],force=True)
        xlen = sizer.pixel_array.shape[0]
        ylen = sizer.pixel_array.shape[1]
        del sizer
        imstack = np.empty((zlen,xlen,ylen),dtype=np.int16)

        for i in range(0,zlen):
            print ('Reading: ' + path + files[i])
            img_raw = dcm.read_file(path + files[i],force=True)
            img = img_raw.pixel_array
            imstack[i,:,:] = img
            slope = img_raw.RescaleSlope
            intercept = img_raw.RescaleIntercept
    #: the ONLY way these are undefined is if you do not enter the loops above
    return imstack, slope, intercept

imstack, slope, intercept = imgstacker('/my/favorite/directory')\
```

## It appears the actual problem was properly escaping the path

WRT paths:
just us / that works for all os's in python and doesnt need rawstrings or escapes but either `path=r"C:\test"` or `path = "C:\\test"` or `path="C:/test"` will all behave correctly, `path="C:\test"` will not

Comment: I'm not sure what you did to change my code here. The way you have it, I get the second error I described: referencing before assignment. Maybe I've been looking at this code too long to see the obvious? What logic am I getting wrong here?

Comment: please put the full traceback ... there is no way this should give you tthat error that you describe ... since it is not a runnable example I cannot run it to verify the solution ...

Comment: you have one return but yet you are overwriting the imstack several times ... and then you are overwriting the slope and intercept(repeatedly) ... all but the last file in the path gets completely disregarded and it only returns the data of the very last file it looks at

Comment: {---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
K:\dir\main.py in <module>()
      6 import matplotlib.cm as cm
      7
----> 8 imstack, slope, intercept = imgstacker('my/favorite/directory\\')
      9 out = temp_test(imstack*slope + intercept)
     10

K:\dir\imgstacker.py in imgstacker(path)
     21                         intercept = img_raw.RescaleIntercept
     22
---> 23         return imstack, slope, intercept

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'imstack' referenced before assignment}

Comment: I'm sorry about how horrible this is, I'm not sure how to copy cmd.exe ipython output cleanly...

Comment: My idea with this is that each 3d layer in imstack is a new image. Am I not doing that? I'm iterating over each layer of imstack and replacing that empty layer with an image layer. the slopes and intercepts don't have to be defined there and they shouldn't be iterated over, but I don't think it hurts anything.

Comment: ok ... im not sure what you are doing ... but at a guess its the wrong thing ... I added the traceback to your original question (you should probably edit it with a copy/paste of the traceback) @SciurusDoomus so do you see your debug print of "Reading: "? I suspect you are not entering either of the loops (ie the folder path is wrong)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the whole function should be indented.

Before defining your function.

```
imstack = None
slope = None
intercept = None
```

Comment: this is not really an answer and almost certainly will not resolve his issue

Comment: I can't get it to format correctly but it's indented properly in my text editor. See comments on the original question, that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Adding these three lines before the last line in global scope will get rid of the referenced before use. At this point removing the global lines may be possible.

Comment: @RobertJacobs It removes one error and replaces it with another. I commented on the original question with the exact error and what I think happened.